# Trying to use moveTaskToBack to background my app if the user selects cancel on a popup, but onActivityResult is called many times

Tags: android, onactivityresult

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == LOGIN_REQUEST) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Do Stuff
        } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

After moveTaskToBack(true) my app is backgrounded, but onActivityResult gets called every time I try to open my app, which immediately backgrounds it again. How do I signal that I've handled the activity result and don't want to be notified about it again?

It should be noted, that I tried this with

```
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

being the first thing in the method as well, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like this, instead of doing it on the `onActivityResult` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```